# Connect GoDaddy Domain Name to Meteor app deployed on linode using MUP?

Tags: meteor, deployment, dns, linode, mup

I am trying to connect a METEOR website hosted on LINODE which i have already deployed using MUP and can be accessed using the ip-address of the linode machine node to a domain name I have on GODADDY. I have tried multiple things. Furthermore, I would like to know how to connect the app to the subdomain under that domain.

Could you please tell me (in as much detail as possible, and specific if possible), or guide me towards the helpful sources? Any help is appreciated.

PS - the suggested tag .htaccess. So, I think this might be a direction I should probe into. I do not yet know anything about .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup nginx as reverse proxy: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/